# Why can't I query table in MySQLWorkbench?

Tags: node.js, macos, mysql-workbench

I have a NodeJS app that uses MySQL. When I open the MySQLWorkbench and select the table the app uses, then click the icon to query the first 1000 rows, it gets stuck (spinning icon) and never shows any results. I can't stop it either. I have to force quit the Workbench.

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with Node.js. Does WB also hang when you query a different schema or even a different server? What does the WB log say? Any hints there if something is wrong?

Comment: I see this when I click "Server logs": Location of MySQL configuration file (ie: my.cnf) not specified. Although the I clearly have a path to /usr/local/mysql/logs/my.cnf set for Configuration File.

Comment: Have you set this path in the connection settings? Otherwise WB cannot find it. Also: I didn't ask for the server logs, but the WB log (see `Help -> Locate Log Files`.

Comment: Where do I set that path in the connection settings? Also, why would a connection string contain a log file path?

Comment: I didn't say you have to set a log file path. My reply was for your claim that you set the path to your config file and I asked if that happened in the connection settings (see `connection editor -> System Profile tab -> Configuration File:`).

Comment: When I click on the server instance in WB, I get this error:        

"Your connection attempt failed for user 'root' from your host to server at localhost:3306:
  Unknown MySQL server host 'localhost' (0)"   

It looks like I need to backtrack and resolve the above. I guess through a completely new question.

Comment: Now the server is working again. I did a query and it doesn't freeze up but returns no results. There should be 2 rows. When I click the analyze icon next to the table, it does report 2 table rows. The 2nd time I tried to query, it got stuck again executing the query. So I'm back on step 1 again.